# PHP form validation, keep field values after refresh

Tags: php, html, validation

I am currently making a registration/validation script for a website and stumbled across a question.

I am using all PHP to validate and using if statements to echo the array of errors.

**My question is:** How can I keep the user's input values in the form after refresh? Must I learn AJAX?

- NOTE: The file I am regarding is `register.php`, which sends data to the same page (`action = ""`). And `form_handle.php` is the actual validation script included at the very top/beginning of `register.php`

`form_handle.php`CODE:

```
    $errors = array();

if( empty($safe_fname) || 
    empty($safe_lname) || 
    empty($safe_email) || 
    empty($safe_email_again) || 
    empty($safe_password) )
        { 
        $errors = '<p>One or more fields left empty'; 
        }
elseif( strlen($safe_password) < 6)
    { 
    $errors = '<p>Password must be atleast 6 charcters long.</p>'; 
    }

elseif($safe_email != $safe_email_again)
    { 
    $errors = '<p>E-mails do not match.</p>'; 
    }
```

`The form` CODE:

```
       <h2>Sign up Today!</h2>
          <form method="post" action="">
                   <span class="p" id="p1"></span><br/> 
          <input name="first_name" id="first" class="register_form cap" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
              <br/><span class="p" id="p2"></span><br/> 
      <input name="last_name" id="second" class="register_form cap" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
          <br/><span class="p" id="p3"></span><br/> 
      <input name="email" id="third" class="register_form" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" />
          <br/><span class="p" id="p4"></span><br/> 
      <input name="email_again" id="fourth" class="register_form" type="text" placeholder="Re-enter E-mail" />
          <br/><span class="p" id="p5"></span><br/> 
      <input name="password" type="password" class="register_form" placeholder="Password" />
          <br/><span class="p" id="p1"></span><br/>   
      <input name="submit" id="fifth" class="register_form" type="submit" value="Create!" />

      </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Just use `value="<?php echo $_POST['first_name']; ?>"` in your HTML?

Comment: Remember to use isset, otherwise you'll get undefined index when the form isn't submitted

Comment: Was encountering this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way to do this and avoid lots of code and errors are as such:

```
<input type='text' name='first_name' value='<?php echo isset($_POST['first_name']) ? $_POST['first_name'] : ''; ?>' />
```

Comment: Doesn't return value after refresh

Comment: I apologize mate, I had my form being echoed as a HEREDOC. Once I took the form out of a HEREDOC the code worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be like

```
<input type='text' name='first_name' value='<?php echo $_POST['first_name']; ?>' />
```

Comment: Might wanna add `isset()` so he avoid undefined index error

Comment: `@$_POST['first_name']` should be more better then `isset()` in above case.

Comment: This code just echoes out the PHP delimiters and all the PHP code

Answer (score 0):

You can try like as follows-

```
<input name="first_name" id="first" class="register_form cap" type="text"
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['first_name'])) {
        echo "value='".$_POST['first_name']."'";
    } else {
        echo "placeholder='First Name'";
    }
    ?>

    />
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but since PHP 7.0.x you can use the null coalescing (`??`) binary operator. The left-hand operand is the expression being evaluated, and the right-hand operand contains the value to be used in case the expression does not exist or is **null**. This eases code reading and eliminates chances of typo errors due to expression replication:

```
<expression> ?? <if-null-value>
```

is equivalent to:

```
isset(<expression>) ? <expression> : <if-null-value>
```

Based on that, I suggest the following answer to the question:

```
<input type='text' name='first_name' value='<?php echo $_POST['first_name'] ?? ''; ?>' />
```